# efficiently swap a python dict's keys and values where the values contain one or more elements

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

Suppose I have a dict:

```
x =  { "a": ["walk", "the", "dog"], "b": ["dog", "spot"], "c":["the", "spot"]  }
```

and want to have the new dict:

```
y = { "walk": ["a"], "the": ["a", "c"], "dog":["a", "b"], "spot":["b","c"]  }
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? If a solution is a few lines and is somehow made simple by a pythonic construct what is it (even if it's not most efficient)?

Note that this is different than other questions where the value is a single element and not a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

y = defaultdict(list)

for key, values in x.items():  # .iteritems() in Python 2
    for value in values:
        y[value].append(key)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y = {}
for (k, v) in x.iteritems():
    for e in v:
        y.setdefault(e, []).append(k)
```

I presented this as an alternative to @Blender's answer, since it's what I'm accustomed to using, but I think Blender's is superior since it avoids constructing a temporary `[]` on every pass of the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily *efficient*, but a one liner just for fun:

```
{b: [k for k, w in x.iteritems() if b in w] for v in x.values() for b in v}
```

The idea here is to iterate over all the values in the original dictionary (`for v in x.values()`), then iterate over all the items in the list (`for b in v`), then use `b` as the key in a dict-comprehension.  The value for `b` is a list comprehension `[k for ...]` where the members are the keys in dictionary `x` for which the value `w` contains the word `b`.

Because the scope is limited you can actually write `v` instead of `w` above, which makes it even harder to understand. :-)

(Edit to add, I'd use @Blender's.  These one liners are fun, but really hard to grok.)